# express-session with mongoDB store creates new session on every login despite including credentials on request

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, cors, express-session

I have an express backend API I am hoping to use for authentication, which is using connect-mongodb-session for the express-session store. However, every time I log in, it creates a new session as opposed to using the already existing one. I have done some research and everyone said to simply include credentials in my request, which I already am doing.

Here's some of the backend:

```js
var corsOptions = {
    origin: `http://localhost:3000`,
    credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

And here's some of the frontend:

```js
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            credentials: 'include' as RequestCredentials,
            mode: 'cors' as RequestMode,
        }

        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/register', requestOptions)
```

As you can see, I have set `credentials: 'include'` and yet it still creates a new session on every login.

Also, not to ask two questions in one but the frontend is written in React and I'm storing the login info with Redux. This causes my application to log out when reloading, is there any feasible way of dealing with this like logging in with the cookies or persisting the Redux store?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the cookie option of express-session to `secure: false` and that seems to have fixed it. Odd, as it was set to true in the first place after someone said that fixed the same issue.

```js
app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.secret,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: { secure: false },
        store: store,
    })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

add these middleware top of session midleware
because browser send option method before post method use this to ignore option method

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
res.send();
res.end();
} else {
next();
}
});
```